# Необходимо чтобы цифра считывалась без нажатия Enter

Tags: c++

Куда мне надо вставить функцию `_getch()`?
Надо чтобы ввел цифру 0 оно сразу экран очистило, или ввел цифру 1 оно через 5 секунд очистило.

```
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int n;
    do
    {
        cout << "введите число: ";
        if (!(cin >> n))
        return 0;
        if (n > 2)
        return 0;
        if (n  == 0)
        {
            system("cls");
        }
        if (n == 1)
        {
            Sleep(5 * 1000);
            system("cls");
        }
    } while (n != 2);
_getch();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Используйте вместо `cin>>`;  `getch()`, а потом проверяйте, что за *символ* введен. Только за 5 секунд ничего не делания обычно пользователь начинает жать все подряд :)

Comment: if (!(n=_getch())) так должно выглядеть?
оно сразу закрывает консоль, как только я ввожу n

Comment: следует наверно  учесть  что Sleep(5 * 1000); и system("cls"); не портируемы. вообще использование system считается плохим стилем (в том числе , это предоставляет злоумышленникам способ запустить их программу с правами ВАШЕЙ программы)

Comment: а чем заменить очистку экрана?
и что означает не портируемые?

Comment: Работает только на WIndows, Заменяют обычно выводом пустых строк, линухе есть другие способы, которые требуют определенной функциональности консоли. В С++11 есть std::this_thread::sleep_for в <thread>, а иначе просто надо делать обертку, чтобы заменить на POSIX sleep

Comment: так а что мне с n=_getch() делать?
Ввожу в консоле любую цифру, оно сразу консоль закрывает.
И если мне к примеру надо задать не один символ а 2 или более?

Comment: _getch() не останавливает исполнение, если ты ждешб нажатие чего-то определенного,  используй do while или другой цикл